# communicate from powershell (Windows) to mongodb server in linux

Tags: linux, windows, mongodb, powershell

my question is very simple, I have:

- Mongodb server running on a Linux server
- Windows machine with powershell

how can I connect my powershell to insert/add/update documents from my Windows (powershell) server to mongodb database instance running on a remote linux server?

I tried using C++ drivers but does not connect.

this is my code:

```
$mongoDbDriverPath = "C:\scripts\CSharpDriver-1.9-rc0\";

Add-Type -Path "$($mongoDbDriverPath)\MongoDB.Bson.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$($mongoDbDriverPath)\MongoDB.Driver.dll"

$dbName = "mydb"
$collectionName = "backupData"
$db = [MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabase]::Create("mongodb://<username>:<passsword>@<IP>:27017/$($dbName)")
$collection = $db[$collectionName]

$document = new-object MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument
$document.Add("PreName",[MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue]::Create("Daniel"))
$document.Add("LastName",[MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue]::Create("Weber"))
$collection.save($document)
```

This is what I get

```
Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to connect to server <IP>:27017: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
connection failed because connected host has failed to respond <IP>:27017."
At C:\scripts\mongo_test.ps1:14 char:17
+ $collection.save <<<< ($document)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Any suggestion?

thank you very much

Comment: mongoimport is not a solution for me because it does not parses dates...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLUTION:

**NOTE**: my linux distribution is Ubuntu 11.04

1. edit your config file /etc/mongodb.conf file with:

   bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
2. restart yout mongodb service:

   /etc/init.d/mondogb restart
3. Add following rules to your IP tables:

   iptables -A INPUT -s  -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A OUTPUT -d  -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
4. make ip tables changes persistent

   iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf

Hope it helpds!

Comment: Thanks for share your solution !! Sometimes users forget to return in order to post their results.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want make queries against your MongoDB server, you can download MongoDB for Windows and use MongoDB Shell (mongo.exe).

```
mongo.exe server/port
```

Then you will be able to make queries, insert documents, etc.

If you want use MongoDB directly from PowerShell, you can use C# driver. [Here is](http://kowalski.ms/2012/07/04/working-with-mongodb-and-powershell/) an example.

Comment: tnanks rubenfa, I already tried that, my problem is connecting from Windows (powershell) to a mongodb server in a remote machine in linux